# c read authentication from url and favicon.ico

Tags: c, url, passwords, favicon

I'm working on a C coded server that have to reply to browsers' requests. It have to give authentication when using url like this:

```
http://user:pass@website/
```

but I really don't know how or where get this information on my server, because what I got when I read the request is the same that I can read when I interact with the server simply using

```
 http://website/
```

Second question is that sometime I have this favicon.ico request from browsers.. what can I reply to the browser to say "I have not this fu***** stupid icon"? :D

I'm of course using socket for this

Comment: Did you read RFCs [2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) (HTTP 1.1) and [2717](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) (HTTP Authentication)?

Answer (score 0):

Look for a request header named `Authorization:` containing the string `Basic` followed by the BASE64 encoded username and password. This method of authenticating is called HTTP Basic Authentication.

For the favicon, simply respond with a HTTP 404 response if you don't have one.

Comment: I'm using firefox.. it should

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean

Comment: The server has to send a response header `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="something"`, which indicates that the client needs to send basic auth credentials using a `Authorization:` request header to access the resource. The browser will only send the `Authorization:` header if the server actually requested basic auth on the resource.